# How can I best check for C library dependencies?

Tags: c, shell, dependencies, package

I'm building something that installs a high-level stack, and to do that, I need to install the lower-level stuff.

The simplest way to look for whether, say, Java is installed, is to just shell out a `which java` in a shell script and check if it can find it. I'm now to the point where I need to do some libraries without an obvious binary- basically stuff that is an `include` from within C. libxml, for example.

I'm woefully green to C in general, so this makes things a little tricky for me. :) Ideally I could just make a shell script that calls a little C applicaiton that calls `#include <xxxx>`, where `xxxx` is the library that I'm checking the existence of. If it can't find it, it errors out. Unfortunately, of course, all that happens prior to compilation, so it's not as dynamic as I'd like.

I'm doing this on a system that probably doesn't have anything installed on it (be it high-level language or package managers or what have you), so I'm looking more for a basic shell script way of doing things (or maybe some clever C or command-line gcc options). Or maybe just manually search the include paths that gcc would look for anyway `/usr/local/include`, `/usr/include`, etc.). Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you want to: 1) at compile time determine that a library (.so) exists, 2) at compile time determine that a header exists (.h), 3) at run time determine that a library exists, or 4) at run time determine that a header exists?  Or something else?

Comment: Also, what's your target OS?  Your use of which suggests a *NIX of some form.

Comment: A useful tool for finding dependencies is `ldd`. Usage: `ldd file`, file could be an executable or shared library.

Comment: Whichever is "safest". Like I said, I usually stay in my safe and nerdy higher-level language world, so I'm open to suggestions. :) From my perspective all I want to know is that "yes, libxml2 is installed on the system", effectively. Also- targeting *nix, multiple flavors.

Answer (score 4):

Autotools is really what you need. Its a huge (and bizarre) framework for dealing with this very problem:
http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/

You can also use `pkg-config`, which will work with newer software making use of that mechanism:
http://pkg-config.freedesktop.org/wiki/

Comment: Is there any way to quickly jump into it without a Makefile and assorted debris? In my most wishful of wishful thinking, all I really want is something like `magic-configure-binary libxml2` to return whether something's available to the system.

Comment: @Zach: I added a note about pkg-config

Answer (score 1):

this is the purpose of configure (part of automake and autoconf)